# Clearing contents of HTMLTableElement

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, overwrite

I have the following table element:

```
<table id="my-table" class="table table-striped table-hover ">Loading...</table>
```

I am dynamically creating the table inside of an ajax call, and then writing the data to the table:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
   success:function(result){
    $.getScript("table-sort-controller.js", function () {
        sortTable("my-table")
    }); //makes table sortable using DataTables
    $.getScript("search-controller.js"); //makes table searchable using DataTables
   },
    url: "http://myserver:8080/url/"
    }).then(function(data) {
    var table = "<thead>";
    table += createTableHeader(data);  //fake method to simplify code
    table += "</thead>";
    table += "<tbody id='sortable-cells'>";
    table += createTableBody(data);  //fake method to simplify code
    table += "</tbody>";
    //This is the line where I try to clear "Loading...".
    document.getElementById("my-table").innerHTML = table;
});
</script>
```

However, I am failing to remove `"Loading..."` from on top of the loaded table.  I have tried the following in the line directly after my table creation:

```
document.getElementById("my-table").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("my-table").empty();
//a few other attempts I cannot remember
```

Some more info:

```
alert(document.getElementById("my-table")); //output is [object HTMLTableElement]
alert(document.getElementById("my-table").innerHTML); //output is empty alert
alert(document.getElementById("my-table").getCaption()); //console says "undefined is not a function"
```

I am unclear as to why `getCaption()` returns undefined, as it appears to be a function under [W3C](http://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/html2/HTMLTableElement.html#getCaption__).

How can I remove `"Loading..."` after my table has finished loading and before I populate `#my-table` with the appropriate HTML?  Alternatively, how can I removing `"Loading..."` immediately after writing my table?

Comment: Don't use invalid HTML in the first place. The DOM tree created by your `<table>Some Text</table>` involves placing the text node before the table. That's why emptying it had no effect. The text is not in the table.

Comment: @Liam that list is not accurate. `<th>` can not be child of `<table>` and you are missing elements

Comment: @Phylogenesis is correct. Your best bet is to include "loading..." inside a dummy `<tr><td>Loading...</td></tr>` row. *That* will actually live inside the table, where it will be removed when you empty the table's contents.

Comment: Downvote for not being knowledgeable in web development?  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Phylogenesis and @Paul Roub, fixed it!

I changed

```
<table id="my-table" class="table table-striped table-hover ">Loading...</table>
```

to

```
<table id="my-table" class="table table-striped table-hover "><tr><td>Loading...</td></tr></table>
```

Then I added following to remove my old `"Loading..."`.

```
$('#my-table').empty();
```

Now it works.  Thanks!

EDIT:  In my particular case, I actually was able to remove the clearing call altogether, as I was overwriting the element in the very next line.

Comment: `<th><td>...</td></th>` isn't particularly valid. Either `<tr><td>...</td></tr>` or `<tr><th>...</th></tr>` would be correct.

Comment: Since you're using jQuery already, I'd much prefer to see `$('#my-table').empty();`.

Comment: @Phylogenesis i tried that first, but it told me undefined function. Something I probably messed up elsewhere

Comment: actually...it should work if I just drop that line altogether I think. Cuz im overwriting innerHTML the very next line

Comment: You tried it as I have written it, or did you try `document.getElementById('my-table').empty();`? The latter will not work as the `empty()` function is provided by the jQuery wrapper.

Comment: @Phylogenesis I did not try it the correct way.  I overlooked the difference.  Awesome! Thanks!!